# Is every locally compact Hausdorff space paracompact?

Tags: general-topology

It seems likely that for any open cover, we can construct a locally finite refinement using the local compactness of the space. I can't figure out how to work the construction though, and I'm not yet convinced that there is no counterexample.

Comment: I can tell you that every _second-countable_ locally compact Hausdorff space is paracompact, as should be shown [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/paracompact.pdf).

Comment: Yes, theorem 2.6, pp. 2-3.

Comment: But without second-countability I wouldn't know…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A locally compact Hausdorff space need not be paracompact. In fact, it need not be normal (and all paracompact Hausdorff spaces are normal).  A basic example is the [deleted Tychonoff plank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank). Consider the product $[0,\omega] \times [0,\omega_1]$ of these two [ordinal spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Ordinal_space) ($\omega$ denotes the least infinite ordinal, and $\omega_1$ the least uncountable ordinal), and let $X$ be the subspace obtained by removing the poing $\langle \omega , \omega_1 \rangle$.

- As a subspace of a Hausdorff space, it is clearly Hausdorff.
- As an open subspace of a compact space, it is locally compact.
- It is not normal because the closed sets $E = [0,\omega) \times \{ \omega_1 \}$ and $F = \{ \omega \} \times [0,\omega_1)$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.

---

Another example of a locally compact Hausdorff space which is not paracompact is the open ordinal space $[0,\omega_1)$.

- As an ordered space, it is Hausdorff.
- As an open subspace of the compact space $[0,\omega_1]$, it is locally compact. (In fact, for each $\alpha < \omega_1$, $[0,\alpha]$ is a compact neighborhood of $\alpha$.)
- Suppose that $\mathcal U$ is an open refinement of the open cover $\{ [0,\alpha) : \alpha < \omega_1 \}$ (essentially it is an open cover with no unbounded sets). Setting $\alpha_0 = 0$, for each $i$ pick $U_i \in \mathcal{U}$ so that $\alpha_i \in U_i$, and let $\alpha_{i+1}$ be the least ordinal not in $\bigcup_{j \leq i} U_j$. Then $( \alpha_i )_i$ is an increasing sequence of ordinals in $\omega_1$, and so has a limit (supremum) $\alpha$. But any open neighborhood of $\alpha$ contains infinitely many $\alpha_i$, and therefore meets infinitely many $U_i$, so $\mathcal U$ could not be locally finite.

Answer (score 4):

[$\pi$-Base](http://topology.pi-base.org) is an online encyclopedia in the spirit of Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*. According to its database, the following spaces are locally compact Hausdorff but not paracompact. (You can view the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=locallycompact%2BT_2%2B%7Eparacompact) to learn more.)

$[0,\Omega) \times I^I$

Deleted Tychonoff Plank

Open Ordinal Space $[0,\Omega)$

Rational Sequence Topology

The Long Line

The Open Long Line

Thomas' Plank

Comment: That is a fantastic resource. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just notices this was already discussed in the first posted answer, let me complement it.

Consider the space of all countable ordinals $[0,\omega_1)=\omega_1$ (this is collection-wise normal, as a linear order, but not paracompact).

One possible way to prove that $\omega_1$ is not paracompact is to use that it is countably compact (= limit point compact) but not compact, and that [countably compact paracompact spaces are compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171182/countably-compact-paracompact-space-is-compact)

Alternatively, you could use the [Pressing-down Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor's_lemma) to prove that $\omega_1$ is not even [metacompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacompact_space). Specifically the open cover $\{[0,\alpha):\alpha<\omega_1\}$ has no point-finite open refinement.